# Handlebars selected option

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

Looking to select an option based on a url

My route is:

```
  router.get('/apply/:id', function(req, res){
  var query = {"status" : "true"}

  Apartment.find(query, function(err, apartments){
    if(err){
      res.status(404).send('Error occured');
    } else {
      res.render('frontend/rental-application', {
        title: 'Apply | LJH Management',
        apartments: apartments,
        wanted_id: req.params.id
      })
    }
  })
});
```

My view is:

```
<select name="propertyofinterest" type="text"/>
    {{#each apartments}}
        <option value="{{address}} {{city}}"{{#if wanted_id '==' _id}}selected{{/if}}>{{address}} - {{city}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

I figured I'd just be able to pass in my req.param.id and set it, However, that's not the case.  I'm getting:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includeZero' of undefined.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you using a custom helper for the comparison in the template?

Comment: No I'm not.  I was just using the standard if

Comment: I'm not sure about the error, but Handlebars doesn't support if comparisons in templates by default, maybe that is what's causing the issue, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787914/index-not-working-in-handlebars